# NFS: disable portmapper for version 3 and 4

Tags: centos, nfs, centos7

I need to replace an old `pcnfsd` server with a newly installed CentOS 7 server. I installed all the requirements and it *seems* to work, sadly when the (very very old ms-dos like) client tries to read the files it gets nothing. The mount is performed correctly but then file access doesn't work.

The only thing I could see on the server is that in `nfsstat -s` I see RPC's **badcalls** increasing.

The current server is an Ubuntu 10, and `rpcinfo -p` shows this:

```
100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
100024    1   udp  50143  status
100024    1   tcp  42419  status
100021    1   udp  35807  nlockmgr
100021    3   udp  35807  nlockmgr
100021    4   udp  35807  nlockmgr
100021    1   tcp  50799  nlockmgr
100021    3   tcp  50799  nlockmgr
100021    4   tcp  50799  nlockmgr
100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
100005    1   udp  45251  mountd
100005    1   tcp  57920  mountd
100005    2   udp  45251  mountd
100005    2   tcp  57920  mountd
100005    3   udp  45251  mountd
100005    3   tcp  57920  mountd
150001    1   udp    967  pcnfsd
150001    2   udp    967  pcnfsd
150001    1   tcp    968  pcnfsd
150001    2   tcp    968  pcnfsd
```

while on the new CentOS 7 I have:

```
100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
150001    1   udp    914  pcnfsd
150001    2   udp    914  pcnfsd
150001    1   tcp    917  pcnfsd
150001    2   tcp    917  pcnfsd
100005    1   udp  20048  mountd
100005    1   tcp  20048  mountd
100005    2   udp  20048  mountd
100005    2   tcp  20048  mountd
100005    3   udp  20048  mountd
100005    3   tcp  20048  mountd
100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
100227    3   udp   2049  nfs_acl
100021    1   udp  40636  nlockmgr
100021    3   udp  40636  nlockmgr
100021    4   udp  40636  nlockmgr
100021    1   tcp  36825  nlockmgr
100021    3   tcp  36825  nlockmgr
100021    4   tcp  36825  nlockmgr
100024    1   udp  57976  status
100024    1   tcp  56153  status
```

I suspect the running portmapper daemons for version 3 and 4 is *confusing* the client.

What I need is to disable advertising of v3 and v4 on the portmap daemon, but I couldn't find the options to do that. How can I?

Comment: multiple version is not a problem as client uses one which is compatible. But may be your client wants to use NFS v2? As Enzo Wang suggested, check the traffic.

Comment: Probably. But as you say it should be allowed to, v2 is offered according to rpcinfo. I'll try debugging as soon as I can, sadly the client is a physical working machine and I cannot disconnect it so easily

Comment: from your post is hard to say which part got an error. So packet capture will help a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the traffic between the old client and NFS server to find out the issue.

On your NFS server:

```
tcpdump -vvv -nn -s 300 -A port 2049 and host $Client_IP -w nfs.cap
```

Open the nfs.cap file with wireshark, you could see the issues I think.

An pic for my nfs.cap is attached.

Here is a very good guide for debugging NFS issues you can have a look stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/NFS-troubleshooting-2.html

To disable certain NFS version support you could probably pass --no-nfs-version X to rpc.nfsd. Search disabling-nfsv4-on-ubuntu.

Check this picture:

[image]

Comment: I made a first test by disabling v4 but I saw no change. I added `RPCNFSDARGS="--no-nfs-version 4"` to /etc/sysconfig/nfs and `rpcinfo -p` still shows portmapper and nfs version 4 listening...

Comment: I accepted your answer even if it's not **the** answer but led me to solve. It was me being too dumb: rpcinfo was showing portmap listening on version 2, but not nfs itself! Adding `RPCNFSDARGS="-V 2"` to /etc/sysconfig/nfs and restarting `nfs-config` and `nfs-server` made nfs listen to version 2 and the client work! thank you both!